# Goroutines throttle example

Tags: go, wait, goroutine

I am learning basic Go via a Udemy course.  In the goroutines section, there is an example of throttling which has thrown my understanding of how wait groups work.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    c1 := make(chan int)
    c2 := make(chan int)

    go populate(c1)

    go fanOutIn(c1, c2)

    for v := range c2 {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }

    fmt.Println("about to exit")
}

func populate(c chan int) {
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        c <- i
    }
    close(c)
}

func fanOutIn(c1, c2 chan int) {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    const goroutines = 10
    wg.Add(goroutines) 
    for i := 0; i < goroutines; i++ {
        go func() {
            for v := range c1 {
                func(v2 int) {
                    c2 <- timeConsumingWork(v2)
                }(v)
            }
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
    close(c2)
}

func timeConsumingWork(n int) int {
    time.Sleep(time.Microsecond * time.Duration(rand.Intn(500)))
    return n + rand.Intn(1000)
}
```

The part that isn't inline with my understanding is in the function `fanOutIn` where the we set up the `WaitGroup`, and `Add(10)`.

Why am I getting 100 values printed out?  Only a single value (`i := 0`) can be put onto `c1`, and the value is never explicitly removed from the channel.  The code then hits `wg.Done()`, and the wait group queue is reduced to 9 and so on.

In my current understanding, I would expect to see 10 values, of `0 + rand.Intn(1000)`.

Comment: "and the value is never explicitly removed from the channel" --- `for v := range c1 {` <- here it's read from the channel.

Comment: It's not obvious why they create an anonymous function there though `func(v2 int) {` - it adds nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function that is spun off reads as follows (including the `go` at the front and the parentheses to call it):

```golang
go func() {
    for v := range c1 {
        func(v2 int) {
            c2 <- timeConsumingWork(v2)
        }(v)
    }
    wg.Done()
}()
```

This code is a little weird and bizarre.  Let's shrink it down even further, discarding the `wg.Done` and keeping only the `for` loop itself:

```golang
for v := range c1 {
    func(v2 int) {
        c2 <- timeConsumingWork(v2)
    }(v)
}
```

There is an inner unnamed function that is pretty useless here; we can discard it without changing the behavior of the program, to get:

```golang
for v := range c1 {
    c2 <- timeConsumingWork(v)
}
```

which is at last a simple loop.  One key question is now this: **How many iterations do you expect from this loop?**  Note:  It is not necessarily any *constant* number.  Perhaps a better way to phrase the question is: **When does this loop end?**

The `for` loop reads a channel.  This kind of loop ends when *a read from the channel indicates that there is no more data*, i.e., that the channel is closed and its queue is empty.  (See [the Go specification section on `for` loops](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements).)

So this innermost loop, `for v := range c1`, is not going to terminate until channel `c1` is closed and there is no more data in its queue.  This channel was created with:

```
c1 := make(chan int)
```

so it has no queue, so we need not even think about that: it terminates after a `close(c1)` closes it.  **You should now look for a `close` that closes `c1`.**

#### Where is our close?

Here's the place that closes `c1`:

```golang
func populate(c chan int) {
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        c <- i
    }
    close(c)
}
```

We call this with `c1` as its argument, so its final `close(c)` closes `c1`.  Now you can ask: **When do we reach this `close` call?**  The answer is obvious: after `i >= 100` in the loop, i.e., after we have sent 100 values, zero through 99 respectively, into channel `c1`.

What `fanOutIn` does is spin off 10 goroutines.  Each of the 10 goroutines runs the first anonymous function I quoted above.  That anonymous function has a loop that runs an indeterminate number of times, repeating until channel `c1` is closed.  Each trip through the loop takes a value of the channel, so initially, if the ten goroutines all manage to start before there are any values available, all ten goroutines will be waiting for values.

When the producer function puts one value into the channel, *one* of the ten waiting goroutines will get it and begin using it.  If that goroutine takes a long time to get back to the top of its own `for` loop, another goroutine will take the next-produced value.  So what happens here is that up to ten *produced* values propagate through the channel to up to ten goroutines.<sup>1</sup>  Each of those (up to ten) goroutines spends some nontrivial amount of time using its value, then sends a final-product-value to channel `c2` and goes back to the top of its own indefinite `for` loop.

Only when the producer has *closed* its channel `c` (which is our `c1` here) will the ten goroutines see a closed-channel-empty-queue, allowing them to exit their `for` loops.  When they do exit their `for` loops, each of them will call `wg.Done()` (once each) and terminate.

So, once the `close(c1)` has occurred (via the `close(c)` in `populate`), *eventually* all ten of these anonymous goroutines will have called `wg.Done()`.  At that point, the `wg.Wait()` in `fanOutIn` will return.  This will call `close(c2)` and return from `fanOutIn`, terminating *that* goroutine as well.

Meanwhile, in `main`, we use `for v := range c2` to read from channel `c2`.  This `for` loop will run when values are written into `c2` by any of the ten goroutines.  It will exit only when `c2` itself is closed (its queue must also be empty but again `c2` has a zero-length queue).  So `main` will not proceed *past* the `for` loop until `c2` is closed, which cannot happen until `wg.Wait()` returns, which cannot happen until ten `wg.Done()` calls have happened, which cannot happen until channel `c1` is closed.

This means that `main` cannot get past its own `for` loop until `populate` has called `close(c)`, and that happens only after generating exactly 100 values.

---

<sup>1</sup>As discussed [in comments below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61719731/golang-goroutines-throttle-example/61720003?noredirect=1#comment109173473_61720003), the phrase *up to* here can be important: we don't really know how many goroutines will really consume values.  A lot depends on how much work each goroutine does, what kind of work that is, and how many CPUs your Go runtime has available.

Comment: It's a great detailed question, one thing though: "up to ten produced values propagate through the channel to up to ten goroutines" --- I think this can be corrected, in this code nothing guarantees that and all 100 values could be consumed by a single goroutine. If probably was a typo, not "up to ten" but "exactly 100"?

Comment: Right, we could have one of the ten goroutines handle all 100 numbers—it's unlikley, but possible, depending on how fast they are produced and consumed, and other scheduling vagaraies.

Comment: I made the (I think reasonable) assumption that the producer would produce quickly and the consumers would consume slowly, with the producer getting to send 10 values into the 10 goroutines: the actual `timeConsumingWork` function calls `time.Sleep`, which gives up the OS-level thread to run other goroutines. Real code might not! If you only have, say, 4 CPUs and all four are very busy, maybe only 4 goroutines at a time actually get any work done, with the other 6 idle all the time.

Comment: Yep, I understand that: `time.Sleep(time.Microsecond * time.Duration(rand.Intn(500)))` --- one goroutine may sleep every time for `0us` and others - for `500us`, then one would consume significantly more than others, this is not a too unrealistic scenario. May be not every time, but if one sleeped 10 times less than others - it would consume +10 to the others.